# Excel VBA: .Formula IF with variables - How to insert quotation marks?

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to mirabeau @ Mrexcel for original script.

**What the original code does**
Sums every range in the K column and adds total to end

**What I want it to do**
Replace the sum with a sumif that sums only the cells meeting the criterion cell, unless the criterion cell containts "Bloomingdales*". Then the entire range should be summed.

**The issue**
I am checking if formula cell.offset(-4,-10) equals the exception. I am however having troubles mixing variables and strings and even variables and variables. Ideally, it should check if e = Store or if e = "Bloomingdales*". Either the code won't execute, or I only get it to display "e=store", where Excel can't interpret the VBA variables.

My attempt:

```
Sub addups()
Dim e As Range, f As Range, g As Range, u As String, x As Range, Store As String
Set e = Columns("K").Rows(2) 'any column and/or start row you like
If e = "" Then Set e = e.End(4)
Do
Set g = e
If e.Offset(1) <> "" Then Set e = e.End(4)
u = Range(g, e).Address(0, 0)
Set f = e.Offset(1)
Set e = e.End(4)
Set x = f.Offset(-4, -10)
Store = "Bloomingdales*"
f.Formula = "=IF("& x &" = "&Store&",Sum(" & u & "),Sumif(A:A," & x.Address & ", K:K))"'Error
Loop Until e.Row = Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Please let me know if you need more info. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Bathsheba's advice here is another method.  A couple of assumptions and a couple of  error fixes.

This little sub also produces the formula without error.

```
Sub insForm()
Dim x As Range, f As Range
Dim Store As String, u As String, qm As String

Store = "Bloomingdales"
qm = Chr(34)
u = "G3:G10"
Set x = Columns("K").Rows(12).Offset(-4, -10)
Set f = Range("B5")

f.Formula = "=IF(" & x.Address & " = " & qm & Store & qm & ",Sum(" & u & "),Sumif(" & "C:C" & ", " & x.Address & ", " & "K:K" & "))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything runs smoothly now. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

To use a quotation mark in VBA, you need to *escape* it using another quotation.

For example `Store = """Bloomingdales"""` will assign a string enclosed in quotation characters.

For clarity, I tend to define a constant

`Public Const vbQuote As String = """"` in one of my modules. Then I can use

`Store = vbQuote & "Bloomingdales" & vbQuote`

which I find more readable.

Comment: Great solution! Will definitely use this in the future. Thanks!